# Aligning divs horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/45/) code.

Wish div align blue with red div without affecting the rest of the page.

Notice that the div#leftcontent not go to the bottom of the page and I'm not understanding why.
Maybe the solution is to put the div#leftcontent aligned to the bottom of the page. But how?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution or are you willing to change the HTML?

Comment: Do you want something like a footer?

Comment: I wish it were only a change in the CSS
I would like the div to stay in red at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Why do you have fixed `width` and `height` for `div#wrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the red div:

```
bottom: 0px; /*delete*/
position:relative;
maring-top: 86px; /*to align to the blue*/
```

check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/85unG/48/

and for the height, the reason the its not touching the bottom is:

div#wrap {
    height: 768px; /*should be 739 px;*/
}

Comment: Note that CSS does not handle `//` comments.

Answer (score 0):

CSS [absolute positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to the rescue!

First ditch the fixed `height` and the `overflow:auto` for `div#wrap`. Replace `overflow:auto` with `overflow:hidden`:

```
div#wrap
{
    width:1024px; 
    /*height:768px; /* Forget about it! */
    margin:5px auto;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    /*overflow:auto;/* Forget about it! */ overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

... now note that `div#wrap` has a relative position:

```
div#wrap
{
    width:1024px; 
    margin:5px auto;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative; /* AWESOME */
}
```

This means `div#wrap` is non-statically positioned, so we can position things absolutely within it... like `div#footer` and `div#social-networks`:

```
div#wrap div#leftcontent div#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
div#wrap div#nav div#social-networks {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

This will position the bottom edge of `div#footer` and `div#social-networks` `0px` away from the bottom edge of its non-statically positioned ancestor - namely, `div#wrap`.

Bad news though: positioning things absolutely can screw up the natural flow of things, so you have to manually reserve some space for `div#footer` and `div#social-networks`. Do this with `padding`:

```
div#wrap
{
    width:1024px; 
    margin:5px auto;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:50px; /* this is new... you can choose a better number than 50px */
}
```